# How to show error logs of a web application in AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I have a web app uploaded in a Apache Tomcat 7.0 Server. That server is in the AWS Cloud. Do you have any idea how I can see the error logs of my web app?

It looks like this

[image]

Do you have any idea how to check this in AWS command line?

This was setup by someone else so I don't know how much access I can have in the AWS.

Comment: AWS commands allow you to manage the infrastructure but doesn't get involved with what's happening inside the machine. Have a look at the EC2 command list to get an idea: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Elastic Beanstalk or managing your own EC2 server? Elastic Beanstalk provides methods to view the server logs. If you are just using an EC2 server you will need to SSH into the server to view the logs.

Comment: Yes, I am managing my own EC2 server. I guess what I need is to know the SSH command lines on how to look into the server.